# awk: print text between two patterns + x lines followed by first match

Tags: awk

Following Input File:

```
#Report Nr. 2343215
#Errors 3243
#Date: (Timestampt)
#Informaiton
#
# Headers
# Specs
DLSLWD 0 0 0 0 Jun 22 01:51:16PM 2018
#List of Objects
#
# Headers
# Paths
Files not found /var/xxxxx
Files not found /etc/xxxxx
Files not found /mnt/xxxxx
Files not found /safd/xxxxx
#
#Reports
#
Error-Number 123
Error Number 12345
#
```

What i need is an awk that pipes the "List of Objects" into a new file:

```
#List of Objects
#
# Headers
# Paths
Files not found /var/xxxxx
Files not found /etc/xxxxx
Files not found /mnt/xxxxx
Files not found /safd/xxxxx
#
```

And the " Reports"into a differnt file:

```
#Reports
#
Error-Number 123
Error Number 12345
#
```

It's a match for #List of Objects + 3 lines until "first" #.

Same for the Reports: Match #Reports + 1 line until "first" #.

At first i tried something like:

```
awk '/#List of Objects/,/#Reports/'
```

For the list of objects followed by:

```
awk '/#Reports/,0'
```

To get the data from #Reports until EOF.

But because `#Reports` and `#List` of Objects are both OPTIONAL and not in every input file I can't use #Reports as the "END-Pattern". so, I have to match on the # but ignore the first X occurrences of # after the matching pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Awk script:`**

**`extract_pat_space.awk`** contents:

```
$0 ~ "^#" pat{ f = 1; hash = 0 }
f { print }
NF == 1 && $1 == "#"{ 
    if (++hash == 2) { f = hash = 0 }
}
```

---

Usage (for both patterns):

```
$ awk -f extract_pat_space.awk -v pat="List" file > list_of_objects.txt
$ awk -f extract_pat_space.awk -v pat="Reports" file > reports.txt
```

---

Results:

```
$ cat list_of_objects.txt 
#List of Objects
#
# Headers
# Paths
Files not found /var/xxxxx
Files not found /etc/xxxxx
Files not found /mnt/xxxxx
Files not found /safd/xxxxx
#
```

---

```
$ cat reports.txt 
#Reports
#
Error-Number 123
Error Number 12345
#
```

Comment: i have no idea what you are doing with this awk, i'm trying to get my head around it, thank you! is it also possible to get rid of all the lines with a # in the output? I would just do a grep -ve '#" on it but would be nice to have this in the awk scrip too.

Comment: @T-One, extend your question according to the mentioned moment

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
    /#List of Objects/ {f = "objects.txt"} 
    /#Reports/         {f = "reports.txt"} 
    f                  {print > f}
' file
```

When you see one of the key headers, set the output filename.
If the variable has been set, print to that file.

Comment: This looks extremly simple, how does awk know where to stop?

Comment: Stop? At the end of file. Are there other criteria I missed?